# Why is there a "/dev/fd/63" in the output of "echo 123 >(cat)"?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors, process-substitution

```
$ echo 123 | cat 
123
```

is doing what I expected, both commands run inside the same shell.

But when I  connect them with the `>( ... )` expression, which connects the output of one command in the shell to a second in a subshell, I get this:

```
$ echo 123 >(cat)
123 /dev/fd/63
```

this is also true with other values:

```
$ echo 101 >(cat)
101 /dev/fd/63

$ echo $BASHPID >(cat)
3252 /dev/fd/63
```

I thought `command1 >(command2)` is the same as `command1 | command2`, but in `command1 >(command2)`, each command is inside a different shell, therefore they should have the same output. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The process substitution `>(thing)` will be replaced by a file name.  This file name corresponds to a file that is connected to the standard input of the `thing` inside the substitution.

The following would be a better example of its use:

```
$ sort -o >(cat -n >/tmp/out) ~/.profile
```

This would sort the file `~/.profile` and send the output to `cat -n` which would enumerate the lines and store the result in `/tmp/out`.

So, to answer you question:  You get that output because `echo` gets the two arguments `123` and `/dev/fd/63`.  `/dev/fd/63` is the file connected to the standard input of the `cat` process in the process substitution.

Modifying your example code slightly:

```
$ echo 101 > >(cat)
```

This would produce just `101` on standard output (the output of `echo` would be redirected to the file that serves as the input to `cat`, and `cat` would produce the contents of that file on standard output).

---

Also note that in the `cmd1 | cmd2` pipeline, `cmd2` may not at all be running in the same shell as `cmd1` (depending on the shell implementation you are using).  `ksh93` works the way you describe (same shell), while `bash` creates a subshell for `cmd2` (unless its `lastpipe` shell option is set and job control is not active).

Answer (score 6):

For completeness

```
cmd1 >(cmd2)
```

is mostly the same as

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

in the `yash` shell, and that shell only.

In that shell, `>(cmd)` is process *redirection* as opposed to the `>(cmd)` of `ksh`/`bash`/`zsh` which is process *substitution*.

It's not strictly equivalent, because in `cmd1 >(cmd2)`, `yash` doesn't wait for `cmd2`, so you may find that:

```
$ yash -c 'echo A >(cat); echo B'
B
A
$ yash -c 'echo A | cat; echo B'
A
B
```

By contrast, process *substitution* expands to a file path (typically a named pipe or a `/dev/fd/<x>` where `<x>` is a fd to a pipe that has been created beforehand) which, when open for writing will allow to  send output to `cmd`.

While process substitution was introduced by `ksh`, in that shell, you can't pass them as argument to redirections.

```
ksh -c 'cmd1 > >(cmd2)'
```

to emulate `yash` process redirection won't work. There, you're meant to pass that file name resulting from the substitution as argument to a command like in:

```
ksh -c 'diff <(echo a) <(echo b)'
```

It will work in `bash` and `zsh`.

However, in `bash` like for `yash`'s process redirection, the shell doesn't wait for the command (`cmd2`). So:

```
$ bash -c 'echo A > >(cat); echo B'
B
A
```

`ksh` process substitution can be emulated with `yash` with:

```
cmd1 /dev/fd/5 5>(cmd2)
```

Like:

```
diff /dev/fd/3 3<(echo a) /dev/fd/4 4<(echo b)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because [that's what process substitution does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), it makes the command inside the substitution appear as a filename. Internally, it connects the commands via a pipe, giving the `/dev/fd/NN` path to the main command, so it can open the already-open file descriptor to the pipe.

It's not the same as a pipe. Pipes connect `stdout` to `stdin` without involving anything that looks like file names. Process substitution is more flexible in that you can have multiple such substitutions in one command line, but it requires the main command to open files by name (e.g. `cat` rather than `echo`).

You can emulate a pipe with process substitution by doing something like this:

```
echo foo > >(cat -n)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 1 >(cat > /dev/null)
1 /dev/fd/63
$ echo echo >(cat /dev/null)
echo /dev/fd/63

# We can trace how the commands are executed
# so long as we avoid using shell builtin commands,
# and run the equivalent external program instead, i.e. /usr/bin/echo

$ strace -f -e execve bash -c '/usr/bin/echo >(cat /dev/null)'
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/echo >(cat /dev/null)"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
strace: Process 4213 attached
[pid  4212] execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["/usr/bin/echo", "/dev/fd/63"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
strace: Process 4214 attached
[pid  4214] execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat", "/dev/null"], [/* 56 vars */]/dev/fd/63
) = 0
[pid  4212] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid  4214] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4214, si_uid=1001, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++

# Apparently, the order of evaluation is arranged so this works nicely:

$ echo 1 > >(cat > /dev/null)
$
```