# `iw dev $interface scan` not working on embedded device

Tags: networking, wifi, embedded, iw

Running on a custom rockchip board with Ubuntu 14.04. I look at interfaces with `ifconfig`:

```
...

wlan3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ea:40:d7:63:27  
          inet addr:192.168.12.1  Bcast:192.168.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::aea:40ff:fed7:6327/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64634 errors:0 dropped:3811 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:868 (868.0 B)  TX bytes:89112 (89.1 KB)
```

I see the wifi interface as the last result.

I try running `sudo iw dev wlan3 scan` which returns `command failed: No such device (-19)`.

I came across [people having a similar issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39601/52005) on the Pi ([additional instance](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=113582)).

Anyone know the cause of this issue or a way around it?

---

**`lsusb`:**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**`uname -a`:**

```
Linux ws1-dev-philip 3.0.36+ #12 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 5 13:22:57 EDT 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @GAD3R same results after using that command

Comment: To get the required information , please add the `lsusb` output and `uname -a`

Comment: @GAD3R question updated

Comment: There are 135 open bugs for the `rtl8188eu`  [see here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/issues/84) including the "iw command not working"

Comment: See my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400113/153195

Comment: Use wicd instead of network manager , configure wicd to use `wext` driver from the GUI, [`wicd_cli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/wicd-cli.8.html) is a command line tool to manage the network.

Comment: @GAD3R thanks seems `apt-get install wicd_cli` returns `unable to locate package`

Comment: enable universe repo then update

Comment: @GAD3R thanks will consider that possibility. Will probably need to get the package approved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nl80211` standard doesn't support the `rtl8188eu` driver , use `wext` the old driver.

To connect use the following command **as root** (you don't need to configure anything);

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -c <(wpa_passphrase "ESSID" PASSWORD) -i wlan3
dhclient wlan3
```

If you have already  a `wpa_supplicant.conf`  configuration file use it as follow:

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan3 -D wext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient wlan3
```

To manage the network from the command line you can use [`wicd_cli`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/net/wicd-cli) available on the `universe` repository after removing the network-manager. Install `wicd` then configure it to use `wext` driver.

Using `wext` driver you should use the deprecated wireless-tools commands , such as `iwlist` , `iwconfig` ...

[Important note from arch linux wiki:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_setup)

> **iw** — iw only supports the nl80211 (netlink) standard. It does not support the older WEXT (Wireless EXTentions) standard. If iw does not see your card, this may be the reason.
>
> **wireless_tools** — wireless_tools is deprecated but still widely supported. Use this for modules using the WEXT standard.

Comment: When I run the first command I get back something about `/dev/fd/63` https://pastebin.com/P5ph6hQg

Comment: the ESSID I'm testing on is "2KLIC Guests" would the space be considered a special character here?

Comment: Related to the `<(...)` ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367849/why-is-there-a-dev-fd-63-in-the-output-of-echo-123-cat

Comment: Result from second command, using `sudo` but operation still not permitted https://pastebin.com/e97rXz3B

Comment: Marking as solved because `iwlist` works, but couldn't get actual answer to work. For future readers.